Fantasy manga about a prince who causes a huge explosion when he loses control of his magical powers as a child
I remember reading this manga around 2013-2014, and at that time, the manga was already finished. It was about this prince who, as a child, loses control of his powers and causes a huge explosion, destroying an entire city. Because of the nature of his magic, the explosion site and surrounding area turned into a literal desert. The prince, at the beginning of the manga, is already in his late teens and lives in a house/hut on the edge of the desert, studying and carrying out experiments, trying to undo the effects of his magic to restore the land.
Loose information that I remember:
When the protagonist was a child, he befriended one of the princes of a neighboring nation, who had been given as a guarantee for a peace treaty. The protagonist spends most of the manga believing that he killed this friend in the explosion, but the protagonist discovers that this friend is alive when he comes to save the protagonist and warns that his kingdom is preparing to start a war against the protagonist's kingdom.
It is also revealed that he had been rescued by someone from his kingdom before the explosion occurred and was being held as a hidden hostage in his own kingdom for political reasons.
The protagonist's mother was something like the king's second or third wife, but she was his favorite; she had black hair.
The protagonist had siblings — I don't remember the exact number of siblings, but I believe it was something like five or seven.
One of the protagonist's sisters was redheaded, had fire magic and had military relevance; she was something like a general.
I think he also had a set of twins as siblings: one had earth magic and could create gemstone, and the other had sand magic.
In the manga world, a type of technology that used elemental magic as fuel had been invented relatively recently and was becoming increasingly popular. The story of the man who invented this technology is shown; He was a miserable street child (probably caused by the explosion) who was hired by a noble merchant after he saw a toy he invented, which I believe used water magic to work.
I remember two important things about the end of the manga: one is that the explosion that traumatized the protagonist had been set up — something was done to force the protagonist to cause the explosion. Another is that, at the end of the manga, the protagonist discovers that, due to the excessive use of magic, the planet/nature is dying; Therefore, he decides to end all magic in the world.

This is The Sign of Abyss.

Humans are born with "signs" that grant them access to the magic that flows throughout the world. When a young prince uses his sign to massacre an entire city, how will he ever find redemption? His is the story that begins from the deepest despair.

It's from 2018, a few years later than you indicated, but otherwise a good fit.
The story is set in a world where each person is born with a mark or 'sign' signifying their ability to utilise a specific type of magic. The 17-year-old protagonist, Jold, is a prince of Cleythula and has the Sign of Abyss. He also has eight siblings, including a twin boy and girl, Belfort and Marfata, and his eldest sister, Lilliankil, a military commander with the Sign of Inferno.
At the start of the manga, Jold is living in exile in a small house in the woods, because eight years earlier, he accidently destroyed the city of Niney with his magic, which he couldn't control. It looked like an implosion rather than an explosion, but left a crater where the city once stood. Jold now spends his time conducting research on how to restore life to that area.



One of the people Jold thought had been killed was his friend Asagith, a prince from the neighbouring country of Ninigynir, who was sent to Cleythula four years before the destruction of Niney as a symbol of peace. In chapter 10, Asagith shows up alive and well and explains that his survival was covered up by the hawks of his country who didn't want peace with Cleythula.



Toward the end of the manga, Jold learns that the Abyss -- a black void in another dimension -- is the source of all magic in the world and craves life in compensation for the magical energy that people have drawn from it. Jold makes the choice to seal the doorway to the Abyss, thereby cutting off people's ability to draw magic from it and causing their signs to disappear.
